# Trouble with Indefinite Integral - $\int \frac{2x^{3}+8x}{\sqrt{(x^{2}+4)}}dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int \frac{2x^{3}+8x}{\sqrt{(x^{2}+4)}}dx$$

I'm having issues integrating this. I found a step through and I do not understand the method of substitution. Would anyone be able to give me a brief explanation how they would integrate this?

I get to this point -
$2\int \frac{x^{3}}{\sqrt{(x^{2}+4)}}dx + 8\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{(x^{2}+4)}}dx$

and then I can't get any further.

Comment: Factor the numerator.

Comment: $2x^3+8x=2x(x^2+4)$. Use this to simplify the integrand and let$u=x^2+4$.

Comment: What Bongers and Mitra said, and a partially non $\LaTeX$ title would also be nice.

Comment: I feel so stupid now. The method I was trying to figure out didn't and I didn't think to try. Thanks!

Comment: @user3431504 Good self answers are also very welcome here. :)

Comment: Now that I have the ability to answer my own silly question,

$\int \frac{2x^{3}+8x}{\sqrt{(x^{2}+4)}}dx$ = $\int 2x(x^{2}+4)^\frac{1}{2} dx$

and becomes $\int u^{\frac{1}{2}}du $ where $du = x^{2}+4$

which is solved as $\frac{2u^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}+c=\frac{2(x^{2}+4)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3} + c$

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing you have found your path, and wanting to keep this out of the throngs of unanswered questions, I present:

$$
\begin{align*}
\int \frac{2x^{3}+8x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+4}}dx &= \int \frac{2x\left( x^2+4 \right)\sqrt{x^{2}+4}}{x^2+4}dx \\
&=\int 2x\sqrt{x^2+4}\, dx.
\end{align*}
$$

Let

$$u=x^2+4.$$

Then

$$du = 2x \, dx.$$

We substitute and solve,

$$
\begin{align*}
\int u^{\frac{1}{2}} \, du &= \frac{2}{3}u^{\frac{3}{2}}+c \\
&=\frac{2}{3}\left( x^2+4 \right)^{\frac{3}{2}}+c.
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, note that $x^3 = x^2 \cdot x$.
Let $t = x^2$ and then trigonometric substitution $t = 2 \sin w$

Second one is easy, substitute $u = x^2 + 4$.